# Creating multiple pages from sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create multiple pages from my query. If I have 100 results, and I want 10 results per page, I would like there to be ten pages created, with each page showing a different query. This is how my query is set up:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM Post WHERE (active ='1') ORDER BY PostID DESC ";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

while(($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
$posts[] = $post;
}


 <?php
if (!$numrows){ echo $errormessage;}
else{


 foreach($posts as $post): ?>

 echo stripslashes($post['text']);  

 <?php endforeach; }?>
```

This pulls each "post" from the database and puts displays them all out.

I would like to do something like this:

```
$results = mysql_num_rows($result);


$numpages = 10/$results; //gives the number of pages

while($numpages<$results)
{

//run code from above\\
}
```

What is the best way to do this with the method that I use? I appreciate your opinions because I'm at one of those stages where I'm lost in my own logic. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most pagination examples fail to meet real life requirements. A custom query string, for example.
So, here is a complete yet concise example:

```
<?
per_page=10;
// Let's put FROM and WHERE parts of the query into variable
$from_where="FROM Post WHERE active ='1'";
// and get total number of records
$sql = "SELECT count(*) ".$from_where;
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$total_rows = $row[0];

//let's get page number from the query string 
if (isset($_GET['page'])) $CUR_PAGE = intval($_GET['page']); else $CUR_PAGE=1;
//and calculate $start variable for the LIMIT clause
$start = abs(($CUR_PAGE-1)*$per_page);

//Let's query database for the actual data
$sql = "SELECT * $from_where ORDER BY PostID DESC LIMIT $start,$per_page";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
// and fill an array
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) $DATA[++$start]=$row;

//now let's form new query string without page variable
$uri = strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"?")."?";    
$tmpget = $_GET;
unset($tmpget['page']);
if ($tmpget) {
  $uri .= http_build_query($tmpget)."&";
}    
//now we're getting total pages number and fill an array of links
$num_pages=ceil($total_rows/$per_page);
for($i=1;$i<=$num_pages;$i++) $PAGES[$i]=$uri.'page='.$i;

//and, finally, starting output in the template.
?>
Found rows: <b><?=$total_rows?></b><br><br>
<? foreach ($DATA as $i => $row): ?>
<?=$i?>. <a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['title']?></a><br>
<? endforeach ?> 

<br>
Pages: 
<? foreach ($PAGES as $i => $link): ?>
<? if ($i == $CUR_PAGE): ?>
<b><?=$i?></b>
<? else: ?> 
<a href="<?=$link?>"><?=$i?></a>
<? endif ?> 
<? endforeach ?>
```

Comment: most of the examples also omit the fact that with big databases, using LIMIT could be an overkill as well... see this for more details: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: @Smejko good point, however I'd just limit number of available pages and ask users to use search instead of going through 1000s of pages

Answer (score 1):

It would be hideous to extract all data from the database and manage it from PHP. It would kill the RAM, and the network.

Use the `LIMIT` clause for paging.

First, you need to see the total number of records. Use

```
$query = 'SELECT count(1) as cnt FROM Post WHERE active =1';
```

then,

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $row['cnt'];

$pages = ceil($count/10.0); //used to display page links. It's the total number of pages.
$page = 3; //get it from somewhere else, it's the page number.
```

Then extract the data

```
$query = 'SELECT count(1) as cnt FROM Post WHERE active =1 LIMIT '.$page*10.', 10';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    //display your row
}
```

Then output the data.

Answer (score -4):

I'm using that similar code to do that:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
$total_data = mysql_num_rows($data);

$step = 30;
$from = $_GET['p'];

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT '.$from.','.$step.'"
```

That code get total rows

and that for creating links:

```
$p=1;
for ($j = 0 ; $j <= $total_data+$step; $j+=$step) 
{ 
    echo ' <a href="page.php?p='.$j.'">'.$p.'</a> '; 
    $p++;

} ?>
```

You can also read about : [pagination](http://www.google.bg/search?q=pagination&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3abg%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=bg&xhr=t&q=how+to+pagination&cp=7&pf=p&sclient=psy&client=firefox-a&hs=bs6&rls=org.mozilla%3abg%3Aofficial&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=how+to+pagination&pbx=1&fp=9cf1db9c5eae3332)

Comment: SQL injection is a thing to be avoided.