# Pagination bug - When I use 'WHERE' in the query, pages do not remember the data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some difficulties in making this PHP pagination work.

Here is the code, http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html.

This works fine, but when I modify the SQL query and use the WHERE clause, it shows the first page of results, but when I change the page the data is lost. What is wrong?

Comment: Please show some actual code here

Comment: There's a comment in their code that says "If you have a WHERE clause in your query you should mirror it here" ... did you do that?

Comment: I've answered this question recently, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019941/creating-multiple-pages-from-sql-query/5020264#5020264

Answer (score 0):

What that comment means is you want to apply the same WHERE conditions (if you have any) to both the queries so your count and actual dataset will be in sync.

```
/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```